# Python on a wiki

Tags: python, tkinter, wiki

I am looking for a way to embed a Tkinter GUI into a wiki page. I have looked around Google for a few hours and haven't had any success with a method. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run Python code directly in a web browser.* You **can** have server-side code that creates images, and client-side JavaScript to manipulate those images and send info back to the server, though.

---

* OK, there's no easy, straight-forward, will-work-for-any-user-on-the-web way to run Python code directly in the browser (see comments and abarnert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604946/1426065)).

Comment: Well, you _can_. There are experimental Python plugins, or you can run the Jython interpreter inside Java applet, or IronPython code inside a Silverlight applet… but yeah, that's not what you want to do.

Comment: ... But while you can indeed run python in a browser, you won't be able to run tkinter. A large chunk of tkinter is binary, and there's not much incentive for anyone to remedy that.

Answer (score 0):

As MattDMo's answer explains, what you want to do is effectively impossible to do *directly*.*

But there are ways to do it indirectly.

---

First, there are in-browser implementations of the Python interpreter, like [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/#) and [Brython](http://brython.info). I don't know if any of them support Tkinter, but they do support some kind of GUI. So, you might have to learn a new GUI framework, but not a new language.

Next, there are Python-to-JavaScript compilers, like [pyjs](http://pyjs.org). This doesn't let you run Python code directly in the browser, but unless you want an interactive interpreter, or need dynamic code generation, that's usually not a problem. Again, I don't know of anything that supports Tkinter, so again you might have to learn a new GUI framework, but not a new language.

If you're willing to learn a new language, but just don't want it to be one as clunky as JavaScript, you might want to consider [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org), which is a language that "works like JavaScript, but looks like Python". Compared to something like pyjs, the JavaScript code generated from your CoffeeScript code will be readable, debuggable, and easier to map back to the original code.

Or, of course, you can just bite the bullet and learn the HTML/CSS/DOM/JS way.

---

Meanwhile, splitting up your program into an "engine" that does the actual work and a GUI front-end in Tkinter is often a good idea in its own right, and it means you have a lot less code to port—you can move the engine directly over to, say, a WSGI web service, and only the front end has to be rewritten.

---

Going in a completely different direction, if you're just trying to support a handful of users, especially on a LAN, there is an option: You can embed VNC (or X11) in the browser (there are many solutions for this; [this one](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) came up first in a quick google), and point each user at a small linux session that does nothing but runs your Tkinter app.

---

* There are experimental Python browser plugins. And you can run a Jython interpreter inside a Java applet, or IronPython code in a Silverlight applet. But these are all bad ideas, and they won't give you Tkinter anyway, just Python.

Answer (score 0):

### Ideas

1. This may sound like a lot of work, but it needs to be done and hopefully it would solve your problem:

   - Make your own web browser that uses the latest Python version instead of JavaScript. In fact, write it in Python, with Tkinter. Then you'll be able to use the widgets more naturally.
   - Tell me. (I might even help.)
   - Make it so you can embed Python Tkinter widgets as you please.
   - Figure out how to make the browser so it's not a magnet for people who like to write malicious Python code, or else have a big disclaimer.
2. Write a plugin and/or extension that either includes or depends upon the Python interpreter and Tkinter, and make the page request that people install it. Make sure your wiki supports plugins, or that your plugin/extension supports wikis that don't support plugins.

As others have said, Python doesn't come with a natural way to make Tkinter widgets in your web browser. You kind of have to make a way, or use someone else's way. If you can put applets in your wiki, I might recommend the Jython method someone else mentioned.